# 301 joomla .htaccess redirect

Tags: html, .htaccess, joomla2.5

We updated Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 and a lot of links changed so we are doing 301 redirect in the htaccess; however i'm running into a bunch that are just not working.

```
redirect 301 /photos-a-movies/photos-of-old-friends/119-halloween/detail/946-604a927.html?tmpl=component http://www.handicappedpets.com/photos-a-movies/media-photos.html
redirect 301 /photos-a-movies/photos-of-old-friends/101-friends/detail/671-dcp0062.html?tmpl=component http://www.handicappedpets.com/photos-a-movies/media-photos.html
redirect 301 /photos-a-movies/photos-of-old-friends/101-friends/detail/1286-barks.html?tmpl=component http://www.handicappedpets.com/photos-a-movies/media-photos.html
```

Maybe its catching up on the crap at the end of the url? Either way...is there a way to 301 redirect say "/photos-a-movies/photos-of-old-friends" and no matter what is after it it gets redirected to a page? Or is there a reason why these 301's don't work?

EDIT:

ok I can get it to work if I do:

```
redirect 301 /photos-a-movies/photos-of-old-friends/101-friends/detail/1286-barks.html http://www.handicappedpets.com/photos-a-movies/media-photos.html
```

Instead of

```
redirect 301 /photos-a-movies/photos-of-old-friends/101-friends/detail/1286-barks.html?tmpl=component http://www.handicappedpets.com/photos-a-movies/media-photos.html
```

Redirects to `http://www.handicappedpets.com/photos-a-movies/media-photos.html?tmpl=component`
but it places the "?tmpl=component" at the end still. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your original redirects didn't work is because you can't match against the query string (the `?tmpl=component` part of the URI) in a `Redirect` directive.

> but it places the "?tmpl=component" at the end still. Is there a way to get rid of it?

You need to add a `?` at the end of the target URL:

```
http://www.handicappedpets.com/photos-a-movies/media-photos.html?
```

The problem with that is after the redirect, you have a stray `?` at the end. If you can't have that, then you'll need to use mod_rewrite instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tmpl=component$
RewriteRule ^/photos-a-movies/photos-of-old-friends/101-friends/detail/1286-barks.html$ http://www.handicappedpets.com/photos-a-movies/media-photos.html? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks a bunch the "?" at the end of the target URL works just fine. I knew I was missing something

Comment: I'm also trying to do something like this:     RedirectMatch 301 ^/photos-a-movies/photos-of-old-friends([^.]+)\.html$ http://www.handicappedpets.com/photos-a-movies/media-photos$1.htm? but it's not 100% working...

Comment: @KDD what do you expect the redirected URL to look like? What's not working about it?

Comment: I am trying to redirect like 100-150 URLS all to [Link](http://www.handicappedpets.com/photos-a-movies/media-photos.html) however the redirect in the comment above still gives a 404 error. I can do them all 1 by 1 with the way you just gave me but I didn't noticed how many of these I had to do until afterwards

Comment: @KDD Oh I see, you want them **all** to go to the same place? Remove the `$1` from your redirect target.

Comment: Perfect! That works great. Thanks for all your help! :) Saves me hours of work on 100+ URL single redirects